# Genetic algorithm selection method stuck at local minimum after few generations

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to write a code for GA to minimize the cost of a system, the problem is that the solution converges towards a local minimum and it gets stuck in it so I can't improve my solution anymore.

it might be my selection method that is causing the problem here is what I have:

```
%----------------------------selection (fittest half) ----------------

probability=ones(1,population/2);
[,IX]=sort(cost(1:population))
dd=sum(1:population);
probability(1:(population/2))=[1:population/2];
probability=fliplr(probability)/dd;


Indexx=IX(1:population/2);
```

then I use Indexx for crossover etc, can anybody suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, optimization solving algorithms converge to a local minimum. To get out of this local minimum in a Genetic Algorithm, you can use mutations. Mutations are applied to some individuals of a generation. Usually, mutations will be bad and make the result worse and they will not be selected for the next generation, but sometimes, a mutation causes an individual to get close to a different (and sometimes better) local minimum. The higher the mutation rate is, the more 'space' will be searched and the higher the chance that the global minimum is found. There is a catch though; If the mutation rate is too high, the algorithm won't converge anymore.

I hope this was helpful for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to play around with the mutations, and I even tried to transfer some random solutions to the next generation every iteration, it made me get some better solution, but still even with very big population I can't converge to the system minimum, and the solution still converges to the local optimum after few generations (10-20). Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: If it converges and doesn't explore more space after generation 20, you could increase the mutation rate even more. You can keep increasing it until either your algorithm does not converge anymore (within 100-1000 generations, depending on how big your search space is) or it converges too slow for your needs (if it's used in for example a game).

Comment: The space is not huge (10^14), and I get stuck even with 1000 population and 100% mutation rate, i guess there has to be something wrong with the steps, maybe more efficient selection,crossover methods ?

Comment: If the algorithm converges with 100% mutation rate (mutation on every individual), something is not right. I can't tell exactly what the problem is, but it could indeed be a selection problem. Crossover is a nice concept as it's using 'good' properties of other individuals to form their offspring instead of just applying mutation and hoping it will be better (crossover is less brute force than mutation, but both or a combination can work fine). Perhaps you could print a few small generations and look if something odd happends (many of the same childs with 100% mutation for example).

Comment: what I meant by getting stuck, is that the solutions in the generations after (10-20) look very similar even with 100% mutation, And  I tired 50 generations 1000 population (would normal find the minimum for such a space) in the last generation's solutions there are a lot of exactly the same solution, what would be the problem in this case in your opinion ?

Comment: With 100% mutation, the best individual of every generation would always mutate and won't be that good individual anymore. If the algorithm keeps converging, I assume the mutation is implemented in a wrong way or your selection is selecting from something else than the last generation. Could you perhaps add your mutation code?

Comment: Hello, I finally was able to solve it by keeping 80% of the population instead of 50% and creating 20% new population. I also had some mistake in the mutation code and now it works fine! thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Well, not only the selection/mutation/crossover operators influence the ability no not get stuck in local optima, but also the representation of the solution and the fitness landscape. The operators and representation you can do something about, but overcoming the fitness landscape is tricky. But there are concepts even for this.

Take a look at some diversity preserving mechanisms (e.g. fitness sharing) and I strongly suggest to take a look at [Novelty Search](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/noveltysearch/userspage/). It's a new (well, not anymore probably, but I learned it as new :)) concept where you don't use the fitness for selection at all. There are also combinations of NS and classical fitness-driven search, look at the Mouret's paper at that page's Publications, or look at my [master thesis](https://cyber.felk.cvut.cz/theses/papers/344.pdf) which is all about combining fitness and novelty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess my problem is simpler than that, because even if I don't have good selection mechanism if should be able to converge with a big population which I can't, even if I use mutation probability of 90% I still get stuck to more or less the same solution (all the solutions in the generations become the same).

Comment: @user2042145 High mutation rate does not necessarily mean that better solutions shloud emerge, more the opposite. If your mutation rate is high you do almost just a random search. The "sameness" of the solutions is exactly the loss of diversity.

Comment: I doesnt work neither with high nor with low mutation rate, do you mind having a look at the selection code that I have and tell me if it's good enough.

Answer (score 4):

maybe my answer arrives too late for your needs, anyhow: starting from the point that GA are not meant to find the optimal solution in a search space, if you system gets stuck in  a local minimum and assuming that  the cone of such minimum is enough steep, the way to get out from it is to 'shake' your population (i.e.  introducing noise). An effective technique is to reduce crossover probability and increase mutation as long as the number of steady generations increases. Together with this, or even before starting to cut crossover probability, you can start introducing fresh, random, individuals in your population, increasing their number as long as your steady generations increase. 
Go back to the initial configuration once the fitness starts to roll again. By the way, a good method to train, while avoiding local minima, is to randomize the allele selected for crossover and to work with large populations, selecting only best 1-2% for the next generation, but of course this higly depends on your search space.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on a particular case of a work experience where I used a genetic algorithm. I used [pymoo](https://pymoo.org), a very nice python framework to solve Multi Objective problems. I had problem similar to you, maybe not the same, but I want to write it here in case someone is going through the same thing, especially using pymoo.

I had to solve a quadratic problem with many constraints, the problem had 2 objectives and two type of variables, binary and real variables, and the real variables had dependencies with the binary ones in some constraints. I had a custom sampling algorithm, which generated a very varied initial population that met all the restrictions of the problem. I Used pymoo's built-in operators for mutation, crossover, and survival and the problem was exactlty with the **survival**. Most of the **survivals** method keep members of the populations who meet the constraints (feasible solution), and the operators of mutation and crossover did not generate feasible population members, then the initial population generated with my sampling could not be overcome in the survival method.
Putting the mutation rate as high as possible did not leave the initial population (I was using uniform crossover and bin bitflip mutation). So i had to do my own mutation and crossover algorithms, and also I introduced a [repair](https://www.pymoo.org/operators/repair.html#:%7E:text=The%20repair%20operator%20is%20mostly,the%20repair%20operator%20in%20pymoo.) operator to handle constraints in each iteration!! **Perhaps the problem is not the parameter setting, but the setting of the operators and the relationships between them.**